# How to build a machine learning model for a multi-label classification problem, in which part of training data contains output which is not exact?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, multiclass-classification

I have a dataset, which contains input and output labels. For most of the data, the output labels are certain. For instance, some data belongs to type A, some data belongs to type B,  some data belongs to type C, some data belong to type D. But there is some special data, which contains only fuzzy information: we only know that these special data does not belong to type A or type B, in other words, it belongs either type C or type D.

So for this type of dataset, how can we employ machine learning method, such as XGBoost etc. to train a classification model? Is there any mature method to deal with this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: Sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to put all those "special data" into a new category named "E" (ideally new category should be -1).
Then the ML model learns those as records that cannot be classified into your known categories based on your training data.

A complex way is to have 4 separate target values.

- Probability of A: P(A)
- Probability of B: P(B)
- Probability of C: P(C)
- Probability of D: P(D)

So for the "special data" where you know that it's not A or B, the values of these fields will be:
P(A):0, P(B):0, P(C):0.5, P(D):0.5
If you have some sort of probability function in your training data, use those instead of equal possibility.

Then predict the probabilities for all 4 using regression and you have more granular outputs.
The outputs with highly skewed probabilities can be put into definite classes and the outputs with a more even distribution can show that the output is also a case of "special data".